# VB.NET - Datagridview: Get index of clicked column

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

In VB.NET's DataGridView, how can i get the index of the column that was clicked on, instead of the one that that has a selected cell.

I wish to provide the user with the option to right click the column and hide it, via a context menu. This code gives me the index of the column that has a selected cell:

```
   Private Sub dataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles dataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
            currSelectedColIdx = e.ColumnIndex
            ContextMenuStrip1.Show()
        End If
    End Sub
```

**Edit:** The problem happens when i bind the contextmenu to the datagridview via the properties window. If i unbind it, the code works correctly.

Comment: you click on the header column ?

Comment: Yes. It still gives me the index of the column that has a selected cell,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CellContextMenuStripNeeded` event of DataGridView.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContextMenuStripNeeded
    If e.RowIndex = -1 Then
        e.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1
        'e.ColumnIndex is the column than you right clicked on it.
    End If
End Sub
```

you can get index of column with : `e.ColumnIndex`.

Comment: This gives me the index of the column that has a cell "active" or selected. Not what i want.

Comment: Yes. I am already using ColumnHeaderMouseClick. Still not what i want. See my code.

Comment: Doesn't work. I've updated my question- The problem only happens when i bind the contextmenu to the datagridview.

Comment: Can you test this code in tell me what index is showing : `Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContextMenuStripNeeded(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellContextMenuStripNeededEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContextMenuStripNeeded
    If e.RowIndex = -1 Then
        MessageBox.Show(e.ColumnIndex.ToString())
    End If
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

Your have probably probleme with declaration of your variable "currSelectedColIdx " :

Please try this code :

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.ColumnHeaderMouseClick
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        Dim currSelectedColIdx = e.ColumnIndex
        ContextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The contextmenu is ok. The problem is that if i have a cell selected in the first column (index: 0) and click on the second column (index: 1), i get the index 0 but i want the index 1.

Comment: Can you show me when your declaration of your variaable "currSelectedColIdx "

Comment: I have edit my answer try it now probably your probleme is the declaration of your variable "currSelectedColIdx "

Comment: It's an integer. 

Dim currSelectedColIdx As Integer

Comment: Ok try to declare it inside the event ColumnHeaderMouseClick look at my  answer i have edit it

Comment: It still gives me the index 0 (column that has a cell that's selected)